# throwing connection Error after uploading the nodejs code on live server however working fine on localhost . I was using mssql to establish connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

***I have uploaded the code on the live server .but whenever I hit the URL (http://hrm.azeemaftab.com/) I am getting following Error:-***

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:

Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
E:\Inetpub\vhosts\azeemaftab.com\hrm.azeemaftab.com\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:39



cfg.options.connectTimeout = cfg.options.connectTimeout ?? this.config.connectionTimeout ?? this.config.timeout ?? 15000
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Inetpub\vhosts\azeemaftab.com\hrm.azeemaftab.com\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\index.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

here is my database connection code config.js

```
const config = {
    user:"user",
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database:"********",
    server:"*****",
    port : *****,
    TrustServerCertificate : true,
    options: {
       trustedConnection: true,
       encrypt: true,
       enableArithAbort: true,
       trustServerCertificate: true,
     },
   };
```

I don't know why I am getting this error . while It is working fine on localhost.

Comment: perhaps the version of node on the server doesn't understand the nullish coalescing operator - seems to be what the error is pointing to. What version of node is running on the server? (must be fairly old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check what version of the node the live server is running. You need to be running node version 14 or higher.